# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'df' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, pandas

I guess I have declared df as `pandas.DataFrame()`.

Why do the code raise `UnboundLocalError`?

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np
from math import log

def half_life(x):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df['Close'] = x
    df['ylag'] = df['Close'].shift(1)
    df['deltaY'] = df['Close'] - df['ylag']
    df = df[1:]
    A = np.vstack([df['ylag'], np.ones(len(df['ylag']))]).T
    results = sm.OLS(df['deltaY'], A).fit()
    halflife = -log(2)/results.params[0]
    return halflife
```

Please help!

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: Please, can you post the complete error including the number line of the error. In this wait I Can see the exactly location of the error in order to make a debug.

Answer (score 0):

[DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/dsintro.html#dataframe)

> DataFrame is a 2-dimensional labeled data structure with columns of
>   potentially different types. You can think of it like a spreadsheet or
>   SQL table, or a dict of Series objects. It is generally the most
>   commonly used pandas object. Like Series, DataFrame accepts many
>   different kinds of input:
>
> Dict of 1D ndarrays, lists, dicts, or Series
>   2-D numpy.ndarray
>   Structured or record ndarray
>   A Series   Another DataFrame
>
> Along with the data, you can optionally pass index (row labels) and
>   columns (column labels) arguments. If you pass an index and / or
>   columns, you are guaranteeing the index and / or columns of the
>   resulting DataFrame. Thus, a dict of Series plus a specific index will
>   discard all data not matching up to the passed index.
>
> If axis labels are not passed, they will be constructed from the input
>   data based on common sense rules.

Note that you are attempting to call Data Frame with no arguments. According to the manual, you must have a data structure and call DataFrame with a data structure argument of a particular type to get a result of a particular type. Look at the examples in the manual that I pointed to to see how pd.DataFrame(d) is set up and print df.type(), df to see what you actually have.